# Android application - using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android development and am looking for someone to help me integrate google maps with my application. Have been trying a few samples I found on the internet but can't seem to get it work. I need to connect google maps with my application and show a route, the same route that I need to create using google maps.

Any help will be really appreciated!

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="--------------------------------------" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutUs" >
        </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Log error:

09-06 08:55:31.325: I/dalvikvm(302): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.
09-06 08:55:31.325: W/dalvikvm(302): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
09-06 08:55:31.325: D/dalvikvm(302): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
09-06 08:55:31.325: I/dalvikvm(302): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.
09-06 08:55:31.325: W/dalvikvm(302): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
09-06 08:55:31.325: D/dalvikvm(302): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
09-06 08:55:31.345: D/dalvikvm(302): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
09-06 08:55:31.345: D/dalvikvm(302): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
09-06 08:55:31.525: W/dalvikvm(302): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment; (30)
09-06 08:55:31.525: W/dalvikvm(302): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;' failed
09-06 08:55:31.535: D/AndroidRuntime(302): Shutting down VM
09-06 08:55:31.535: W/dalvikvm(302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avpanelswalks/com.example.avpanelswalks.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:128)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.example.avpanelswalks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  ... 11 more
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.avpanelswalks-1.apk]
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-06 08:55:31.555: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  ... 19 more

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about an issue you are having - this question is too general.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find better instructions than the **Google Documentation**:

1. **[Get an API Key for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=de)**
2. **[Add a map to your Application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_a_map_to_an_android_application)**
3. **[Use the Google Directions API to request the routes you need](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)**

**More information**
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

**Update:**
Try using a **SupportMapFragment** (com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment)
instead of **com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment** in your **layout.xml**.
You also need to extend **FragmentActivity** then instead of **Activity**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah it seems pretty decent but I need to integrate the google maps with my app first. Cannot seem to get it working!

Comment: That's because you need an API-key and permissions and stuff, it's pretty complicated actually.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link on how to get the key

Comment: try reading the links @MartinGolpashin has shared..it is very detailed

Comment: If there are still problems, you can always ask in a more detailed thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help all. Does anyone know of a project which includes what I'm looking for that I can find useful?

Comment: I followed step 1 all the way but the app is crashing once it starts. Any help?

Comment: it could be anything. you need to post detailed information with a stacktrace

Comment: you should also post a stacktrace if the app crashes

Comment: Just updated the question the the log. Thanks for helping me mate :)

Comment: Any help with my problem?